# How to see what route was taken in optimization experiment?

Tags: anylogic

I'm building a model in AnyLogic that determines the optimal delivery route for a truck. I've been able to find information on other data output, but looking through AnyLogic help, I haven't been able to find a feature which will tell me what exact route the truck took. Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build-in functionality but you can easily do it yourself. The specifics depend on what you mean by "route" but I assume you mean a GIS route? In any case, the approach is similar:

1. create a collection inside your truck agent. The type depends on your type of route but I would suggest a LinkedHashMap
2. create an event in the truck that cyclically logs the current truck position into the collection

You can optimize this by only using the event when the truck actually moves.

Comment: Hello, thank you! This is very helpful. Since I'm new to AnyLogic, I'm not entirely sure how to create such an event that cyclically logs the truck's position. Might you be able to point me in the right direction? Thank you so much again!

Comment: Check out the help on events to understand them: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fstatecharts%2FEvents.html :-) . Also, you'd need to provide more details on your model and agents: is it GIS? How does it choose/optimize a route... But best do that in a new question "How can I log my position regularly" or similar. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make it easy for us

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I'm new to stack overflow, so this is helpful. I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434533/how-can-i-log-my-position-regularly-in-a-gis-model

Thanks again!

Comment: good. Please mark answers as "answered" if they were helpful. This helps future users to find them easier ;-)