# How can I log my position regularly in a GIS Model?

Tags: anylogic

I have a GIS model where a truck leaves a main distributor, visits several customers along a route to make deliveries, and then return to the distributor once it is empty. The route is chosen based on proximity of agents to the main distributor and to each other. I'm trying to figure out how to log the route the truck took in order to make the deliveries, though I have not been able to do so yet. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what exactly do you want to log? GIS coordinates every second? GIS coordinates when the truck changes direction? Street names taken? cheers

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! I would like to log street names taken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log street names (as you do):

You can't.

Not with the free GIS map service that pulls data from OSM. I believe that you could do it from Google Maps services but it is very expensive... Your only chance is to download OpenStreeMap shapefiles of the area of interest, convert them into a network of paths and pull the street names from there.

The OSM shapefiles *should* have street names in their dbf files and you can specify in the AnyLogic GIS map object in which column of your dbf file the street names are located. Then, upon converting to path objects, AnyLogic will name the path object according to the street name.

But to be honest, this is not trivial and might be overkill for you. Maybe think about logging something else?

Comment: I see! In that case, it might be overkill. GIS coordinates every time the truck changes direction might be better, then.

Answer (score 0):

In order to log coordinates i would use a collection of type GISRoute. This is the type you are getting anyway when calculating route for your truck. And GISRoute contains an array of segments (GISMarkupSegment). And every segment has a start and end (type Point) with its lat and lon (methods getLatitude, getLongitude).